# How threads are renewed in case of Java's ThreadPool?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

When I look at Java's `Thread.State` enum, I see that there are following thread states-
`NEW`, `RUNNABLE`, `WAITING`, `TIMED_WAITING`, `BLOCKED` and `TERMINATED`.

I've always read and heard that whenever thread finishes its execution, it terminates. So how `ThreadPool` manages to renew the existing worker thread after its execution of current task completes? Is there any additional thread state in case of `ThreadPool`?

Comment: Are you aware that you can install the source together with the JDK and see for yourself?

Comment: Since you've marked it 'duplicate', can you point me to the original question where it has been answered?
I've taken look at Java's sourcecode and have failed to understand how it is achieved hence the question.

Comment: The duplicate is linked at the top of your question.